# Output of int i = 10 + + 11 - - 12 + + 13 - - 14 + + 15; and how?

Tags: java, int, operators

Unable to determine how the output comes?
I ran this code and the answer comes as 75:
Please tell the logic for this.

```
public class MainClass{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int i = 10 + + 11 - - 12 + + 13 - - 14 + + 15;

        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: `- -` yields `+` , you are basically doing a sum of all your numbers.

Comment: What number were you expecting, and why?

Comment: That is not even a java question but a **basic** math question, what is `1 - - 2`?

Answer (score 6):

You have to understand how to operators is work ;

```
int i = 10 + +11 - -12 + +13 - -14 + +15;
        10 + 
             11 (- - =>) +
                           12 (+ + =>) +
                                         13 (- - =>) +
                                                       14 (+ + =>) + 
                                                                     15
```

The end result is :

```
int i = 10 + 11 + 12 + 13 + 14 + 15;//===> 75
```

Answer (score 4):

In Java, `a - - b` is parsed as `a - ( -b )`.  The first `-` is subtraction.  The second one is negation.  But (from high school maths) subtracting a negative number is the same as adding a positive one ...

Likewise, `a + + b` is parsed as `a + ( +b )` .... etcetera.

---

<sup>Warning: If you ever write code like that in real life, the velociraptors will get you: https://xkcd.com/292/</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Here `--` acts as `+` and `++` acts as `+` *(Basic mathematics logic)*.

So basically you are making sum of all numbers.

Logically

```
 int i = 10 + + 11 - - 12 + + 13 - - 14 + + 15; // i=75
```

Becomes :-

```
 int i = 10 + 11 + 12 + 13 + 14 + 15;   // i = 75
```

Answer (score 0):

I executed this in C++ and I found the same answer that is 75.
What I concluded is,
it checks the operators **- -** if we multiply the signs then it becomes **+** plus therefore it adds all the numbers.
I tried a counter example for you that is

```
int i = 10 + +11 - -12 + +13 - +14 + +15;
```

its output is **47** which is **10 + 11 + 12 + 13 - 14 + 15**. that means in this case (-,+) with 14 becomes - so it subtracts 14 from the amount calculation starting from left according to rules.

Thanks for improving  knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainClass   {

  public static void main(String[] args)
   {
    int i = 10 + + 11 - - 12 + + 13 - - 14 + + 15;

    System.out.println(i);
   }
}
```

> > what is happening here?
> >     It is that 10 + (+ 11) and what are we able to see 10 + + 11 
> >     from this operation it will get the value as 21
> >
> > Then coming to second 21 - (-12) but we are seeing it as 10 + + 11 - - 12 = 33
> >
> > Then Third case 33 + + 13 but it is 10 + + 11 - - 12 + + 13 = 46
> >
> > Then coming to fourth 46 - (-14) but we are seeing it as 10 + + 11 - - 12  + + 13 - - 14 = 60
> >
> > Then coming to fifth 60 + (+14) but we are seeing it as 10 + + 11 - - 12  + + 13 - - 14 + + 15=75

**This is all happening because - - is addition**